# Diode direction for door pin trigger

Tags: diodes, logic-gates, wiring, automotive, decoupling

Which direction should the diode, cathode or anode, be facing for a car security alarm wire? Below is a diagram.

When the doors are closed, the wires are testing at 10.1 volts, settings on the system could be set for either negative or positive door trigger input.

Does a system that tests wires as always on when doors are closed means it's a negative door trigger?

[image]

Comment: That little white line is usually indicating the cathode. https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/polarity/diode-and-led-polarity

Comment: yeah stripe end of the physical diode is the bar end of the diode symbol.

Answer (score 2):

That diagram is not very useful, since all the switches depicted are in parallel, so you only need one connection, but if there were several lamps  to be lit separately e.g. in the trunk or under the hood, you'd need the diodes to prevent a single switch from pulling all the circuits on (low) at the same time.

For that situation, the diodes as illustrated would be correct. The cathode, as Eugene points out, is the end with the stripe, and this is a negative side switch - the connection you are monitoring is held high by the bulb until a switch closes.

Comment: @Jasen, Usually, alarm systems are designed to work with 12 V input signals.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the fact that most alarm systems have only one (usually negative) input to accept contact sensors that produce 0 V (ground) when a door, bonnet, trunk, etc. is opened. It is internally connected with a pull-up resistor to  12 V. The triggering logic is such that it is enough for at least one of the sensors to provide "ground" and the alarm system input becomes LOW. So all sensors must be connected via a logical OR circuit (with respect to ground) to the input of the alarm system.

For a number of reasons, for many years this has been done (or at least that is how we did it in the 90s) with several diodes connected in a logic circuit OR with common anodes and cathodes connected to the sensors. We connected them on the spot and sometimes we did nоt solder them. A lot of cars were stolen and we could not equip them (not that they were not stolen later; for example, my almost new Mazda was stolen in 2016). Of course, it would be best to have several separate inputs (zones) of the microcontroller.

These "decoupling diodes" allow the sensors to control their lamps separately and independently of each other and to be correctly read from the car microcomputer... and at the same time to produce a common signal when at least one of them is "on".

There is another reason to include such diodes - to stop the flow of a relatively large current from a lamp to the input of the alarm system.  This would be dangerous not so much for the alarm system (there is an input inside) but for some additionally connected sensor (ultrasonic, microwave, etc.) with an "open collector" output. The transistor just burns out.